# margin environment in preample

Tags: margins

I've been using a code obtained with much help from others on here.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\definecolor{framerule}{RGB}{183,41,41}
\colorlet{tryit}{green!70!black}

\newcommand\RedBox{\textcolor{framerule}{$\square$}}

\newtcolorbox{eoexample}{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  check odd page,
  toggle left and right,
  boxrule=0pt,
  colback=white,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  top=\topsep,
  bottom=\topsep,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  overlay unbroken ={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit) 
      at ([xshift=\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north east) 
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east) -- 
        ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.north east);
      \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=east]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};  
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.south west) -- 
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \else
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit) 
      at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north west) 
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west) -- 
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.north west);
      \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=east, outer sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at (frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};  
      \draw[framerule] 
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.south west) -- 
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \fi
  },
  overlay first={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit) 
      at ([xshift=\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north east) 
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east) -- 
        ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.north east);
    \else
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit) 
      at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north west) 
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west) -- 
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.north west);
    \fi
  },
  overlay last={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[inner sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};  
      \draw[framerule] 
        (frame.south west) -- 
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \else
      \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=east, outer sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at (frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};  
      \draw[framerule] 
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.south west) -- 
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \fi
  }
}

\newtheoremstyle{myexa}% name
  {\topsep}%Space above
  {\topsep}%Space below
  {}%Body font
  {}%Indent amount 1
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {.}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}%Space after theorem head 2
  {}%Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{myexa}

\newtheorem{exa}{Example}

\newenvironment{example}[1][]
  {\begin{eoexample}\begin{exa}}
  {\end{exa}\end{eoexample}}  

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{example}
This is a worked out example.\\
\marginnote{\flushleft{\color{framerule}{
Simplify $i^{100}$.}}}[-.75cm]

The solution is typed here, which may go from one page to the next.  The margin can be used to include tables, graphs, or a similar example with answer (but no solution). The question should be right under the line. The answer is above the second line, all in the margin.\\
\lipsum[1] 
\marginnote{\flushleft{\color{framerule}{Answer: 1.}}}[-1.2cm]
\end{example}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{example}
This is a second example. \\
\marginnote{\flushleft{\color{framerule}{
Simplify $i^{101}$.}}}[-.75cm]

Include the solution here. 
\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{\flushleft{\color{framerule}{Answer: $i$.}}}[-1.2cm]
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Right now to type the text in the margin, I have to use the \marginnote command and adjust the location at the end of the line. Is there anyway I can put this code in the preamble, inside the eoexample code?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the top and bottom marginnotes handled automatically yes?

Assuming so I would replace the definition of your `example` environment with

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{example}{oo}
  {\begin{eoexample}\begin{exa}%
    \IfNoValueF{#1}{\marginnote{\flushleft{\color{framerule}{#1}}}[-7.5mm]}}%
  {\IfNoValueF{#2}{\marginnote{\flushleft{\color{framerule}{#2}}}[-12mm]}%
   \end{exa}\end{eoexample}}
```

This environment now has two optional arguments for the top and bottom margin notes so you can write:

```
\begin{example}[Simplify $i^{100}$][Answer 1]
This is a worked out example.\\

The solution is typed here, which may go from one page to the next.  The margin can be used to include tables, graphs, or a similar example with answer (but no solution). The question should be right under the line. The answer is above the second line, all in the margin.\\
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}
```

*EDIT*
The OP noticed that the answer is placed incorrectly when it is longer than one line. t really ought to be possible to cater for this automatically, but I haven't found a good way to do this. Instead, I have found a hack that gives an easy way for adjusting for this by adding another optional argument to he example environment:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{example}{ooO{12}}
  {\begin{eoexample}\begin{exa}%
    \IfNoValueF{#1}{\marginnote{\flushleft{\color{framerule}{#1}}}[-7.5mm]}}%
  {\IfNoValueF{#2}{\marginnote{\flushleft{\color{framerule}{#2}}}[-#3mm]}%
   \end{exa}\end{eoexample}}
```

For single line answers you use as before but for multiple line answers the third optional argument can be used to correctly adjust the placement of the box:

```
\begin{example}[Simplify $i^{101}$][Answer: $i$ that is really really really long][18]
This is a second example.

Include the solution here.
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}
```

This gives the desired output:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[depthadjust]{marginnote}

\definecolor{framerule}{RGB}{183,41,41}
\colorlet{tryit}{green!70!black}

\newcommand\RedBox{\textcolor{framerule}{$\square$}}

\newtcolorbox{eoexample}{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  check odd page,
  toggle left and right,
  boxrule=0pt,
  colback=white,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  top=\topsep,
  bottom=\topsep,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  overlay unbroken ={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit)
      at ([xshift=\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north east)
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east) --
        ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.north east);
      \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=east]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.south west) --
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \else
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit)
      at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north west)
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west) --
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.north west);
      \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=east, outer sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at (frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.south west) --
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \fi
  },
  overlay first={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit)
      at ([xshift=\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north east)
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east) --
        ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.north east);
    \else
      \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
      (tryit)
      at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north west)
      {You Try It!};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east);
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west) --
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.north west);
    \fi
  },
  overlay last={%
    \ifoddpage
      \node[inner sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};
      \draw[framerule]
        (frame.south west) --
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \else
      \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=east, outer sep=0pt]
        (box)
        at (frame.south east)
        {\RedBox};
      \draw[framerule]
        ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.south west) --
        ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \fi
  }
}

\newtheoremstyle{myexa}% name
  {\topsep}%Space above
  {\topsep}%Space below
  {}%Body font
  {}%Indent amount 1
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {.}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}%Space after theorem head 2
{}%Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{myexa}

\newtheorem{exa}{Example}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{example}{ooO{12}}
  {\begin{eoexample}\begin{exa}%
    \IfNoValueF{#1}{\marginnote{\flushleft{\color{framerule}{#1}}}[-7.5mm]}}%
  {\IfNoValueF{#2}{\marginnote{\flushleft{\color{framerule}{#2}}}[-#3mm]}%
   \end{exa}\end{eoexample}}

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{example}[Simplify $i^{100}$][Answer 1]
This is a worked out example.\\

The solution is typed here, which may go from one page to the next.  The margin can be used to include tables, graphs, or a similar example with answer (but no solution). The question should be right under the line. The answer is above the second line, all in the margin.\\
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{example}[Simplify $i^{101}$][Answer: $i$ that is really really
  really long][18]
This is a second example.

Include the solution here.
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is awesome. precisely what i want. and very clean. thank you ;)

Comment: For the second \ifNoValueF, if the text is only one line, then it is fine (above the line). But if the text is more than one line, then one text line is above the red line and one text line is below the red line. Can I have it set up so that the last text line is always above the red line?

Comment: @SeanN I have added a hack for manually adjusting the placement of long answers. It's not great as I'd prefer this was automatic...

Comment: Hi Andrew. This is great. Although it is not automatic, it is actually very versatile because I can use the code for cases where I don't need the second entry to be just right on top of the line, but perhaps in the middle. Thank you so much for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? This sets things up so that the second note can be passed as an optional argument to `example`. I used the second as it is not clear to me what you would want done with the first. Since that one is placed in the middle of the example content, it presumably may vary in location.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\definecolor{framerule}{RGB}{183,41,41}
\colorlet{tryit}{green!70!black}

\newcommand\RedBox{\textcolor{framerule}{$\square$}}

\newtcolorbox{eoexample}{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  check odd page,
  toggle left and right,
  boxrule=0pt,
  colback=white,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  top=\topsep,
  bottom=\topsep,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  overlay unbroken ={%
    \ifoddpage
    \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
    (tryit)
    at ([xshift=\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north east)
    {You Try It!};
    \draw[framerule]
    (frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west);
    \draw[framerule]
    ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east) --
    ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.north east);
    \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=east]
    (box)
    at ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.south east)
    {\RedBox};
    \draw[framerule]
    (frame.south west) --
    ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \else
    \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
    (tryit)
    at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north west)
    {You Try It!};
    \draw[framerule]
    (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east);
    \draw[framerule]
    ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west) --
    ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.north west);
    \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=east, outer sep=0pt]
    (box)
    at (frame.south east)
    {\RedBox};
    \draw[framerule]
    ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.south west) --
    ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \fi
  },
  overlay first={%
    \ifoddpage
    \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
    (tryit)
    at ([xshift=\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north east)
    {You Try It!};
    \draw[framerule]
    (frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west);
    \draw[framerule]
    ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east) --
    ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.north east);
    \else
    \node[draw,tryit,fill=white]
    (tryit)
    at ([xshift=-\marginparsep-0.5\marginparwidth]frame.north west)
    {You Try It!};
    \draw[framerule]
    (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=3pt]tryit.east);
    \draw[framerule]
    ([xshift=-3pt]tryit.west) --
    ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.north west);
    \fi
  },
  overlay last={%
    \ifoddpage
    \node[inner sep=0pt]
    (box)
    at ([xshift=\marginparsep+\marginparwidth]frame.south east)
    {\RedBox};
    \draw[framerule]
    (frame.south west) --
    ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \else
    \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=east, outer sep=0pt]
    (box)
    at (frame.south east)
    {\RedBox};
    \draw[framerule]
    ([xshift=-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth]frame.south west) --
    ([xshift=-3pt]box.west);
    \fi
  }
}

\newtheoremstyle{myexa}% name
{\topsep}%Space above
{\topsep}%Space below
{}%Body font
{}%Indent amount 1
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{.}%Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}%Space after theorem head 2
{}%Theorem head spec

\theoremstyle{myexa}

\newtheorem{exa}{Example}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
  \gdef\final@marginnote@example{#1}%
  \begin{eoexample}\begin{exa}%
    }{%
      \def\tempa{}\ifx\tempa\final@marginnote@example\relax\else\marginnote{\flushleft{\color{framerule}{\final@marginnote@example}}}[-1.2cm]\fi
    \end{exa}\end{eoexample}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

  \lipsum[1-4]

  \begin{example}[Answer: 1.]
    This is a worked out example.\\
    \marginnote{\flushleft{\color{framerule}{
          Simplify $i^{100}$.}}}[-.75cm]

    The solution is typed here, which may go from one page to the next.  The margin can be used to include tables, graphs, or a similar example with answer (but no solution). The question should be right under the line. The answer is above the second line, all in the margin.\\
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{example}

  \lipsum[1]

  \begin{example}[Answer: $i$.]
    This is a second example. \\
    \marginnote{\flushleft{\color{framerule}{
          Simplify $i^{101}$.}}}[-.75cm]

    Include the solution here.
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi everyone. I have been using this template with no problem thus far. After I installed mac os x sierrra and reinstall TeXShop, it seems that LaTeX no longer check ifoddpage. What should be on the right margin is now on the left. Does anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: @SeanN You should comment on Andrew's answer since that's the solution you are using. (At least, so your green tick says.) But probably you should ask a new question. However, if Sierra is not yet released, then you should not ask here at all but on the relevant mailing list. Ask in chat if you're not sure where that is. (I have nothing later than Tiger, so I'm not really aware of the latest happenings in Apple's Domain.)

Comment: @SeanN However, it is very unlikely that the problem is caused by a change to your OS. So probably best to post a Minimal Working Example of the problem as a question first.